# Does Typescript have Operator Overloading?

Tags: typescript, operator-overloading

My question is if there is operator overloading in typescript, if it exists I could give an example or a link where you can read about it.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

No it does not exist. It is very unlikely that it will exist unless there is a clear Spec on how it might be implemented in Pure JavaScript.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but why would operator overloading be needed in pure Javascript, in order for TypeScript to support it? Couldn't the TypeScript compiler, for example, convert a + operator in the TypeScript source with a function call in the JavaScript output.

Comment: `Couldn't the TypeScript compiler, for example, convert a + operator in the TypeScript source with a function call in the JavaScript output` It *could* but that would defeat what TypeScript is all about `Add or rely on run-time type information in programs, or emit different code based on the results of the type system. Instead, encourage programming patterns that do not require run-time metadata.` https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals#non-goals

Comment: As long as the operator type checks, it could just be translated into a specific function call. The dependency on the type system would only be during compilation.

Comment: It is totally unnecessary to have operator overloading in native javascript for this to work.

Comment: Typescript has many, many examples of new syntax like this one.

Comment: Regarding `It could but that would defeat what TypeScript is all about 'Add or rely on run-time type information in programs'`. I would want the TypeScript compiler to detect the script at compile time, and then replace === with a function call (for example)

Comment: @benathon Doable, and I would say possibly even a good idea  But not going to happen for TS, too left field for their ideology 

Comment: look at how kotlin did it. The operators are named functions, but in code you can use operators

Answer (score 12):

> is there is operator overloading in typescript

No, and the TypeScript project doesn't seem interested in implementing this new feature unless it's first added to JavaScript. (I can respect wanting to [avoid scope creep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericgu/minus-100-points) in their project.)

I *was* hoping that a new version of ECMAScript would implement operator overloading. See this language proposal: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-operator-overloading

---

Updated in 2024:

It's been decided to `Withdraw` the proposal.

I think I found the meeting notes with the details for why it won't be added to ECMAScript: https://github.com/tc39/notes/blob/main/meetings/2023-11/november-28.md#withdrawing-operator-overloading

> #### Speaker's Summary of Key Points
>
> - Operator overloading was proposed to solve many problems with JS, including enabling different numeric types, unit-bearing calculations including CSS units, more ergonomic vector/matrix processing, and generalizing BigInt/Decimal.
> - Several JavaScript engine maintainers held that operator overloading does not have the right cost/benefit tradeoff to be worth it to implement. It would be very hard to implement efficiently, especially with the scoping/safety features.
> - Given the positions in committee on operator overloading, DE proposed withdrawing operator overloading, which may clear the way for proposals such as Decimal, where “whether to overload operators” is a pertinent design discussion.
>
> #### Conclusion
>
> - TC39 reached consensus to withdraw the operator overloading proposal, pending SYG’s confirmation, which was given after the meeting.
> - The withdrawal is due to the high cost to implementations and high complexity of the operator overloading proposal, or any other possible proposal in this space.
> - Operator overloading may be re-introduced to TC39 in the future (especially if implementers' perception of the cost/benefit tradeoff changes), but the committee currently does not expect to spend time investigating operator overloading.

Comment: Anybody know whats up with that proposal?  It seems like it was last active around 4 years ago, and no indication there whether its under consideration still or just abandoned.

Comment: @GGizmos we got an update! ...but not a good one