# typescript: cast overloading

Tags: typescript, casting

I want to write a minimal helper-library in typescript, which allows to define a complex object using method chaining (for test-automation). Example:

```
select().byAttr1("test").and().attr2("test");
```

The result of the chain should be passed to a function of an external npm library. As the parameter of the function has an own type, i am using a conversion method "toLibrary()" which converts my "method-chain-typ" to the library type:

```
extLibray( select().byAttr1("test").and().attr2("test").toLibrary() );
```

This is working, but for me (personally) the last method call is "code bloat".
Is there a way to get rid of the last "toLibrary" method, and instead use some kind of overloading, which automatically instructs typescript to call "toLibrary" when the object should be casted to a specific type?

PS: I am aware (or at least think) that typescript does not support actual overloading ( i.e. [Does Typescript have Operator Overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36110070/does-typescript-have-operator-overloading) ), but maybe there is a smart way, to avoid the last call with some other method.

Comment: Such "code bloat" is normal for the builder pattern… but what do you mean by "casted to a specific type"? If you mean a TypeScript [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions), then what you want is impossible; as part of TypeScript's static type system, type assertions are [erased](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure) from the emitted JavaScript, so there's nothing at runtime to trigger a `toLibrary()` call. Can you post a real [mcve] so someone can make other suggestions that might work for you? Good luck!